# How to stream video in python from youtube

Tags: python, youtube, video-streaming

i used to solve this problem pafy. But now this library not working, because youtube change something and pafy haven't any udate. So i need to new way.

Comment: maybe wait for update in pafy. If youtube changed something on page then all modules will need update

Comment: I found new library. Pytube https://pypi.org/project/pytube/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found new library.The library is called Pytube https://pypi.org/project/pytube/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).